# Switching to a new workflow

Tags: sitecore

We have a need to apply a new workflow to items in our content tree. This will replace the Workflow already in place.

I have a base item that these content items inherit from, so I can use that to change the default Workflow.

The problem is, how do I deal with items that are already in the various states of Workflow? Do I have to edit them individually to put them in the equivalent step of the new Workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions, **yes**. However, maybe consider switching them programatically rather than manually. Maybe you can run code to go through the items and switch WF states based on mappings from the old to new states. I recommend you post this question on the SDN forum or even ask Sitecore support as there may be consequences to doing this.

Comment: I've done something like this, it's actually pretty straightforward.  Just make a call to SelectItems and then update the appropriate fields... I believe" __Workflow" and "__Workflow state".  There is an API for setting the State, but not the workflow, so far as I know.